# Adding a link on click of login

Tags: community, napili, login

Can I make 'Login' as hyperlink and redirect to an external page?
Is there any way to remove the existing link?

Comment: Did the below answer help you? please consider accepting the answer if yes, if not, please leave a comment to follow up, if the answer leads to other questions, please create a new post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the standard login component of napili and redirect user when make click. (You can view these component on lightning components section in setup)

But if you want to manage the login from another place you should look the other login options for community `Single Sign-On Settings or Auth. Providers`

You can read more in these links:

[Single Sign-On](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_about.htm&type=0)

[Auth. Providers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=0)